# PHP fgetcsv() delimiter

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, readfile

Regarding to [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) documentation, there are some parameteres inside `fgetcsv()` function:  Handle, length, delimiter, enclosure, and escape.

Now, I have 2 questions:

1. What does enclosure do exactly?
2. I have a csv file with 5 columns per line. Imagine it something like this: *1,2,3,4,5*

So indexes are from 0 to 4. But whenever I want to get date from index 4, an empty value returns. Unless I put a comma after it (by filling an extra column after it that makes the contents like this: *1,2,3,4,5,6* ). How can I solve this issue ? It seems that there is some problem because of missing comma after the last item in each row of csv file!

Comment: Could you paste the csv file somewhere? And maybe show us some revelant part of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The `enclosure` parameter is the character the encapsulates the data for a specific field, or "index". By default, the parameter is a `"`, which means that you can "enclose" strings in `"` characters.

Example:

```
1,2,"this is three",4
```

2. Per a comment, you're calling `fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',')`. It's possible, maybe, that the line(s) you're reading are longer than 10000 characters. Try changing the length to `0`, which will be "no limit" and see if that helps. Another solution would be to try wrapping the column's value in double-quotes.

Comment: I read lines using `while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',')) !== FALSE) {` and fetch their values like `$title = $data[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Enclosure is the character *enclosing* the field. It is an extra delimiter, of a sort.

For example `hello,world` has a comma as **field** delimiter, and has no **text** delimiter, while `"hello","world"` has a quote sign as **text** delimiter. Some systems employ delimited and undelimited values to indicate text and numeric fields, respectively (I believe Microsoft Excel does). This allows a field to contain the field delimiter in its value:

```
"Hello,world","Second Field","Third, and last, field".
```

Some other systems only enclose values containing the field delimiter, or values containing whitespace, which means that on those systems *an undelimited value is not necessarily numeric*.

If you have a "trivial" case - undelimited values, without escaped field-delimiters inside values (i.e., no 'A,firstpartB\,secondpartB,C' stuff) - you might skip CSV conversion altogether and run

```
  $line = fgets($file, MAX_EXPECTED_LINE_LEN);
  // This splits '  A, B, C ' into 'A', ' B' and ' C' (note spaces)
  $row = explode(',', trim($line)); // other delimiters can be used
```

or

```
  // Consider "  , ", "," and ", " as the same delimiter
  // i.e. ' Alpha , Beta   ,    Gamma  ' gets split into 'Alpha', 'Beta' and 'Gamma'
  $row = preg_split('#\\s*,\\s*#', trim($line));
```

I cannot seem to reproduce the problem you are experiencing; could it be related to a different encoding of line endings (i.e., CRLF instead of LF)?

In a pinch, you can divide `fgetcsv` in the two components `fgets` and `str_getcsv()`, manipulating the line between the calls (with `trim`, or if the worse comes to the worst, by appending the missing comma).

Answer (score 0):

It works to me on this way:

```
while ($row = $stmt -> fecht()){
     echo "\"";
     echo $row['email'];
     echo "\"";
     // Export every row to a file
     $arr = array(',');
     fputcsv($data, $arr, ";", '"' );
}
```